# Handling two different I2C devices on the same port

Tags: android, linux, printing, serial-port, i2c

I have (Android) device that has integrated bar code scanner and printer (device name: gc068 pos).
The printer and bar code devices both appear under same port, /dev/ttyS1 but work on a different baudrates.
If I open both of them at the same time, I can't operate them correctly. If I open only one, everything works just fine.
How are this things handled? Is open port -> command -> close port the only option for me?

Comment: I2C is a serial bus, what do you mean by "If I open both of them at the same time"?

Comment: mPrinterSerialPort = new SerialPort("/dev/ttyS1", 115200, 0);  
mBarCodeSerialPort = new SerialPort("/dev/ttyS1", 9600, 0);